# usage of visitor pattern

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a class like this

```
 public  EmployeeRepositoryImpl{
    public Employee save(final Employee employee) {

      return    employeeDao.save(sanitizeEmployee(employee));
       }

        Employee sanitizeEmployee(Employee employee){

            employee.setName(cleanUpBadData(employee.getName());
            employee.setPhone(cleanUpBadData(employee.getPhone());
            employee.setAddress(cleanUpBadData(employee.getAddress());
      ......

            return employee;
        }

    private static String cleanUpBadData(String attribute) {
            //cleanbaddata here
            return attribute;
        }
    }
```

I want to refactor this  using visitor pattern incase tomorrow we need to add additional logic like  cleanup Which I added today.I am not sure I did visitor pattern correctly since I do not have a accept method and Visitable.Can anyone please correct me the right way to do it.

I created

```
public interface EmployeeVisitor {


    void visitEmployee(Employee employee);

}

public class EmployeeVisitorImpl implements EmployeeVisitor {

public void visitEmployee(Employee employee)
{

                employee.setName(cleanUpBadData(employee.getName());
                employee.setPhone(cleanUpBadData(employee.getPhone());
                employee.setAddress(cleanUpBadData(employee.getAddress());
          ......

                return employee;
            }

        private static String cleanUpBadData(String attribute) {
                //cleanbaddata here
                return attribute;
            }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like a good fit for a visitor pattern.

Comment: What pattern can be used here .The use case is  tomorrow there can be some more logic to add just like sanitize the data.May be sanitize xml bad characters.

Comment: Why do you need a pattern? Just update your `cleanupBadData()` method.

Comment: Why does your code look so messy? You should let your IDE format it automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A correct implementation of the visitor pattern would look like this:

```
interface EmployeeVisitor {
    void visitEmployee(Employee employee);
}

class CleanUpEmployee implements EmployeeVisitor {
    void visitEmployee(Employee employee) {
        ...
    }
}

class Employee {
    void accept(EmployeeVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visitEmployee(this);
    }
}
```

The visitor pattern is specifically designed to separate one or more algorithms from a class structure they operate on. There is no point to the visitor pattern unless there is a class structure you are trying to make your algorithms independent of. In your case you don't seem to have any extensions of `Employee` so there's really no value to using visitors - just make the algorithms methods of the class.

If your intention is to be able to add additional operations to the class without changing it then there are other patterns that are probably more useful. For example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern allows the behaviour to be selected at runtime and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern allows the behaviour to be encapsulated with its context.